# How to create a method inside the onPostExecute?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, methods, android-asynctask

I tried to put if else inside the button onClick

Here's the onClick

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                ettext.getText().toString();
                viewword.getText().toString();
                select();

                if(viewword.equals("")) {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Does not exist in database.1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    sendChatMessage();
                }


        }
```

Here's the onPostExecute

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView disp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view);
            try {
                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                word = json_data.getString("server_response");
                disp.setText(word);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                disp.setText("");
            }

        }
```

The problem is that the app is not reading the if else statement and proceed to onPostExecute. My solution was to create a method inside the onPostExecute but I don't know how.

Comment: Hint: stop doing android for the moment. Just learn the essential java basics. **Android** is an advanced topic, and you dont even understand the rules how to write correct Java code. Seriously: you are trying to run, without the slightest idea how one crawls. Learn Java. Otherwise your experiments with Android will be nothing but frustrating; because nothing will work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here isn't onPostExecute but your code.

> viewword.getText().toString();

This is just a String value and you need to store it in some variable when you are checking if it is null or not. Hence your code should be either

> `String checkVariable =viewword.getText().toString();
>       if(checkVariable.equals(""){
>   \\your code}`

or

```
if(viewword.getText().toString().equals("")
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried the code that you gave me but a new occured. If I entered a word, the database can't read and it says the word doesn't exist even if it does exist. Is there any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a method in a method, you can create a method in the `AsyncTask` class and call it in `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I didn't get it :(